# Uploadify (or other) file selector dialog with checkboxes or greyed prior uploads

Tags: uploadify

Does Uploadify offer any of the following options?

In the file dialog that is shown to users, display a checkbox rather than enable a CTRL + mouse click to allow the user to specify the items to upload.

In the file dialog that is shown to users, show in grey the items that have been uploaded already.

Display a tree view of files rather than present a file dialog.

If you know of a different library that does allow these features and is cross-browser compatible, please let me know, too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It does not support any of these because the flash player which is used for Uploadify (Although nowadays there is also HTML5 implementation for which I cannot speak because I know it not) does not support them.